# Is there a way to emulate the mootools "domready" event without needing the full framework?

Tags: javascript, mootools

Is there a way to emulate the mootools "domready" event without needing the full framework?

I want some javascript that decorates some of my textboxes to run before the onload event because i'm seeing a flicker of the un-decorated boxes before it runs. Ideally i'd like to hook in as the page is loaded but before it is displayed.

And i don't want to require the full framework, that is overkill for my purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen this before? Should do the trick for you:

http://ryanmorr.com/archives/ondomready-no-browser-sniffing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MooTools core builder](http://mootools.net/core) to build just a part of the framework (you just need the core and native suites).